# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NullReferenceException was enhandled

Tags: c#, arrays, object, instantiation

Below code creates the error message in the subject line. Could you please help?  I am trying to instantiate below class as an object.  I think the error is caused by the array that I am trying to declare.

```
class DataStuff
{
    public double G { get; set; }
    public double[,] M { get; set; }

    public void UpdateData()
    {
        G = 500;
    }

    public void UpdateMatrixData()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                M[i, j] = i + j;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know which line causes the exception?

Comment: You don't say where the error was. But I'll take a guess and say it's in
    `M[i, j] = i + j;`
as you never created the array (with new).

Comment: It's all in the error, you can't use `M` without first initializing it, use a debugger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***create*** `M[,]` matrix instance ***before using*** it:

```
class DataStuff {
  ...
  // M is null; an instance should be created 
  // Usually, "private set;" instead of "set" is a better design
  public double[,] M { get; set; } 

  public DataStuff() {
    M = new Double[2, 2]; // <- M is created in the constructor
  } 
  ...
}
...
DataStuff test = new DataStuff();
test.UpdateMatrixData();
```

Comment: Dmitry, so how about public double G { get; set; }?  Don't I need to do anything to it?  Is it because M is an array and it is different?

Comment: A double is a value type and can be used directly. An array (of anything) is a reference type and has to be `new`ed.

Comment: @Ujae Kang: `Double` type in `Double G` is a struct, not class (as array is) so you don't need creating `G`. In fact, `G` will be initialized with `0.0` value

Comment: How on earth can you use **M** for property and and array..?           this is wrong code!

Comment: @HackerMan: You can use any type (array included) in property. Not that good design, but still is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        M[i, j] = i + j;//if you are trying to access the property..this is wrong!
//you cant access the property like an array
    }
```

if you want to access the property like array use indexer

```
public double[,] this[int i,int j]
{
get;
set;//enter your code here!
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access the property